# Dual comparator sort sorts list with repeated, wrong, pattern

Tags: java, android, arrays, list, arraylist

So I have an object called group, of which many are stored in an ArrayList.

Group:

```
long id;
String name;
String logo;
Long time;
String message;
boolean pinned = false;

public Group(String name, String logo, long time, String message) {
    this.name = name;
    this.logo = logo;
    this.time = time;
    this.message = message;
}
public Group makePinned(boolean pinned) {
    this.pinned = pinned;
    return this;
}
```

To the ArrayList, I add groups as follows:
Adding Groups:

```
Group group = new Group(
        new BigInteger(130, new java.util.Random()).toString(32),
        "PB",
        (long) (Math.random() * 1649157582577L),
        new BigInteger(260, new java.util.Random()).toString(32)
);
if (Math.random() > 0.9) {
    allGroups.add(group.makePinned(true));
} else {
    allGroups.add(group);
}
sortGroups(allGroups);
```

I display this ArrayList in a RecyclerView on Android, however I want to sort this list by 2 factors: Primary, whether they are pinned or not, and secondary, what their time is.
I do this by sorting them twice, with a different comparator each, and then reversing the list so that the latest time is always on top:

Sorter:

```
public static void sortGroups(ArrayList<Group> list) {
    list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Group::getTime));
    list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Group::isPinned));
    Collections.reverse(list);
}
```

To test this, I created 56 groups and displayed them in their order after they have been sorted.
When displaying them however, they group into a weird pattern:

- for one, all unpinned groups are, even if not in the same consecutive non-pinned groups row, sorted by time
- all pinned groups are sorted by time the same as all unpinned ones, with the exception of the first consecutive row

overall, without regarding the pinned status of the groups, all but index 0 through 7 are sorted by time from top to bottom

- Index 0-7: Pinned, sorted by time (other than all others)
- Index 8-10: Unpinned (highest of 8-56)
- Index 11-18: Pinned, sorted by time
- Index 19-21: Unpinned
- Index 22-29: Pinned, sorted by time
- Index 30-32: Unpinned
- Index 33-40: Pinned, sorted by time
- Index 41-43: Unpinned
- Index 44-51: Pinned, sorted by time
  Index 52: Unpinned (Pattern broke likely due to not enough groups)
  Index 53-56: Pinned, sorted by time (lowest of 8-56)

Here is a scrollshot of how the groups are displayed on my phone, time was translated from timeInMillis to datetime:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmhuX.jpg

Comment: You are not chaining the sorts properly. First you sort by the time, then you overwrite the sort by sorting again by `pinned`. `Comparator.comparing(Group::isPinned).thenComparing(Group::getTime)` could work

Comment: Oh... My... God... Thank you so much that fixed it. I thought it would do the same thing, since they would only be sorted by 1 and 0 after. Thank you

Comment: Umm @XtremeBaumer so I just added your method and it seems like it worked for the first time, however after adding some more groups the exact same issue reproduced as described above

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fully functional example for your case. It works as expected. If you get different results when displaying, then you should have a look at your displaying method, as that one probably mixes the groups again (or uses a data type that doesn't ensure order)

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Group> allGroups = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            Group group = new Test().new Group(("grp" + i), (long) (Math.random() * 1649157582577L));
            if (Math.random() > 0.9) {
                allGroups.add(group.makePinned(true));
            } else {
                allGroups.add(group);
            }
        }
        sortGroups(allGroups);

        for (Group g : allGroups) {
            System.out.println(g);
        }

    }

    public static void sortGroups(List<Group> list) {
        list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Group::isPinned).thenComparing(Group::getTime));
        Collections.reverse(list);
    }

    private class Group {
        String name;
        Long time;
        boolean pinned = false;

        public Group(String name, long time) {
            this.name = name;
            this.time = time;
        }

        public Group makePinned(boolean pinned) {
            this.pinned = pinned;
            return this;
        }

        public Long getTime() {
            return time;
        }

        public boolean isPinned() {
            return pinned;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Group [name=" + name + ", time=" + new Date(time) + ", pinned=" + pinned + "]";
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Well I am using an Android RecyclerViewer to display them. I am also quite certain that it should work. Is there something where the RecyclerViewer might get the data differently than one would think?

Comment: I don't know much about Android specifically, but it seems that you need to implement some stuff on your own to even get the data into the 'RecyclerViewer' (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#java). Perhaps you have errors there

Comment: So here is my full RecyclerAdapter (https://paste.md-5.net/ecodekocuq.java). But I think the problem cannot be there, since it sorts the groups correctly if the pinned groups are not considered

Comment: `public void filter(String charText)` overwrites the `private List<Group> groups;` value. When resetting here `groups = new ArrayList<>(allGroups);`, you have unfiltered data passed into it, as you only sort when creating the adapter `sortGroups((ArrayList<Group>) passedGroups);`. So perhaps you want to sort `allGroups` as well or ensure that after resetting/filtering the data, the `groups` list is sorted again

Comment: I sorted allGroups and groups both before and after the filter, however this changes nothing with how the result behaves

Comment: Is `groups` in `onBindViewHolder` sorted? Don't check what you view, debug it and check list content

Comment: After trying out and debugging for a while, I found out that for some reason, the groups which were displayed as pinned further down were actually reporting false as isPinned(). Since my method to display the pinned icon only checked if they were pinned and made it visible, it never made the reused rows have an invisible icon if they were not in fact pinned. This lead to the observed behaviour. So the one extra check has fixed the issue and the sorting algorithm was correct both with my old way and your new (better) way, and it was the Recycler which had the problem. Thank you for your help